# How to add an HyperLink field by code but with an image instead of a text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a gridview and one of the columns should be a link, but instead of text I need an icon.

How can I accomplish that?

```
  HyperLinkField bCSLink = new HyperLinkField();
            bCSLink.NavigateUrl = "CsLink"; ??
            grdiview.Columns.Add(bCSLink);
```

Comment: Check this..http://forums.asp.net/t/1291954.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Set the Text your HyperLink like this.....

```
bCSLink .Text = @"<img src='"+ResolveUrl("Path of Image of Delete Icon")+"' /> ";
```

Comment: its a webpart and it has to be done by Code, not using anymarkup

Answer (score 0):

Use a template field.

```
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="myHyperLink" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="imSomething" runat="server" SkinID="Something" />
                    <asp:Image ID="imSomethingElse" runat="server" SkinID="SomethingElse" />
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then make the image you want to display Visible and the other ones non Visible.